# Does Joule Heating happen in all materials?

Tags: thermodynamics

Does Joules Heating apply only to certain materials? Say,the ones with high resistance? Because why would all the work done get converted to heat in all kind of materials.(Heat= Work = VIt = I^2RT).Some of the energy is used for useful work right, as in fans.

Comment: Many parts of the National Electrical Code (or your local equivalent) are all about dealing with the heat generated from the wires in you house, and keeping your house from burning down...

Answer (score 1):

> Does Joules Heating apply only to certain materials?

No. It applies to any material that is carrying current, even if the resistance is very high so that current is very low.

> Some of the energy is used for useful work right, as in fans.

Of course. But in order to perform useful work current must flow in conductors and all conductors (with the exception of superconductors) have resistance which dissipate some of the energy as heat (a.k.a. Joule Heating).

The product of rms voltage and current, $V_{rms}I_{rms}$ is the "apparent power of the load". Only the in-phase voltage and current equals the dissipated, or real power, $I_{rms}^{2}R$. The real power divided by the apparent power is called the "power factor" of the load.

The simplest way to determine the real power dissipated in a load (that which causes Joule heating) is to use a watt meter. It measures only the in-phase product of voltage and current.

Hope this helps.